# Formulario Visual_Aluno

Tags: php

boa tarde,
Como faço para visualizar o nome da variável que está no formulário como este por exemplo: END_MUN_PESSOA quero visaulizar o nome do municipio e não o código. Segue o print da tela:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cole aqui o código que gera essa página e talvez dê pra ajudar.

Comment: Resolvi Ricardo Moraleida obrigado

Comment: Uma outra dúvida é essa:
bom dia,
Como faço pra carregar numa combobox no formulário de cadastro de aluno somente cursos disponíveis pra se inscrever conforme essa ideia:
dtinicial é >= dtfinal de inscrição do curso
se for sim (ele mostra no combobox)
se não for (ele não mostra no combobox)
Isto no formulário de cadastro de aluno.
Isso será feito com a parte do curso e usar uma comparação de dtinscrição inicial com a final

Comment: Legal Carlos. Adicione uma resposta com a sua solução pra ajudar quem tiver um problema semelhante depois. E abra uma nova pergunta pra outra dúvida.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/3Gu65nz7

(Resolução do visual_aluno.php) onde mostra o nome puxado pelo cod. correspondente pelo bd.